# Подключение библиотек C++

Tags: c++, dll, lib

Решил добавить gtest к решению. Создал проект для тестов, подключил в него gtest.lib и gtest.h.

Собрал lib проекта, которого буду тестировать, подключил к тестам и прописал добавочные пути включения к хидерам тестируемого проекта(ТП).

Заинклюдил хидер ТП к тестам - неразрешённый внешний символ на функции класса из ТП.

Дальше заморочился с импортом и экспортом, но не получилось.

Код ТП:

```
#if defined ( KLibEditorDLL )
#define EXT_KLibEditor __declspec( dllexport )
#else
#define EXT_KLibEditor __declspec( dllimport )
#endif 

class EXT_KLibEditor Import
{
public:

    Import();

    ~Import();

    static bool ImportElement(const char* pathLibrary, const char* pathElement);
}
```

Код тестов:

```
#include "Import.h"

...

TEST_F()
{

    std::string zipName = "C:\\Users\\malenkov\\Desktop\\Test\\маша.zip";
    std::string fileName = "C:\\Users\\malenkov\\Desktop\\Test\\маша.txt";

    ASSERT_TRUE(Import::ImportElement(zipName.c_str(), fileName.c_str()) == true);
}
```

Чего ещё нужно сделать?

Comment: "но не получилось." - это как? И что у вас за компилятор/IDE/система сборки?

Comment: Такая же ошибка с внешними символами. VS2015 и соответсвенно MSBuild.

Comment: "Такая же ошибка" это какая?

Comment: "неразрешённый внешний символ" на функции класса из ТП, в данном случае на функцию ImportElement

Comment: Вам нужно подключить lib-файлы, а как - догадайтесь сами, это ничуть не сложнее чем догадаться о полном тексте ошибки. Удачи.

Comment: Да это я сделал